# Column heading does not appear

Tags: python, pandas

Does anyone know how I can get a column heading for my first column. The column is v1?

```
v1 = ['AAPL','MSFT','TSLA','FB','BRK-B','TSM','NVDA','V','JNJ','JPM','WMT','PG','BAC','HD','BABA','TM','XOM','PFE','DIS','KO']
```

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import numpy as np

# For custom list of stocks, edit this list below, otherwise leave commented out
v1 = ['AAPL','MSFT','TSLA','FB','BRK-B','TSM','NVDA','V','JNJ','JPM','WMT','PG','BAC','HD','BABA','TM','XOM','PFE','DIS','KO']
# Header required to scrape from Finviz
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36',
           'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1', 'Cookie': 'v2=1495343816.182.19.234.142', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
           'Referer': "http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="}
    
# This function is what is used to find the metric of interest and return it
def fundamental_metric(soup, metric):
    return soup.find(text=metric).find_next(class_='snapshot-td2').text
    
# This function iterates through the index of the data frame (stock_list) and uses the fundemental_metric functinon to find the metric on Finviz for that stock
# Any stock in the list that cannot be scraped will return an error before moving on to the next stock
def get_fundamental_data(df):
    for symbol in df.index:
        try:
            #url = ("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" + symbol.lower())
            r = requests.get("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="+ symbol.lower(),headers=headers)
            soup = bs(r.content,'html.parser')
            for m in df.columns:
                output = fundamental_metric(soup,m)
                df.loc[symbol,m] = output
                df.replace(['-'], np.NaN)
        except Exception as e:
            print (symbol, 'Not Found')
            print(e)
        return df
    
# List of metrics to scrape
# Before adding any metrics, ensure the metric being added is available on Finviz and the name is matched identically
metric = ['Sales','Income']
    
df = pd.DataFrame(index = v1, columns = metric)
df = get_fundamental_data(df)
    
print(df)

**Results**

         Sales     Income
AAPL   365.82B     94.68B
MSFT   184.90B     71.19B
TSLA    53.82B      5.52B
FB     112.33B     40.30B
```

**Results**

```
     Sales     Income
AAPL   365.82B     94.68B
MSFT   184.90B     71.19B
TSLA    53.82B      5.52B
FB     112.33B     40.30B
```

**Desired Results**

```
v1       Sales     Income
AAPL   365.82B     94.68B
MSFT   184.90B     71.19B
TSLA    53.82B      5.52B
FB     112.33B     40.30B
```

Comment: You question is unclear, what is not working?

Comment: I'm not getting a column heading for column1. I want the heading to say v1.

Comment: You mean the index?

Comment: I put up the desired results. Maybe I do mean the index, not sure.

Comment: Then you want to name and reset the index, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70915955/16343464)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to name your index. You can use `rename_axis`:

```
df = df.rename_axis('v1')
```

output:

```
        Sales  Income
v1                   
AAPL  365.82B  94.68B
MSFT  184.90B  71.19B
TSLA   53.82B   5.52B
```

And to move the index as column:

```
df = df.rename_axis('v1').reset_index()
```

*NB. you see that there is now an new, unnamed, range index*
output:

```
     v1    Sales  Income
0  AAPL  365.82B  94.68B
1  MSFT  184.90B  71.19B
2  TSLA   53.82B   5.52B
```

Answer (score 0):

After your code, you can use `df.rename_axis('v1', axis='columns', inplace=True)`. This would create your desired output.

Comment: Actually, this won't. It will look like it if the index is unnamed but what this does is to the the columns index name. Try to `reset_index()` or to `rename_axis('XXX')` to see how it fails

Comment: I did not understand your point.

Comment: Your code won't set 'v1' as name for the AAPL/MSFT/TSLA index, this is not what OP what looking for